# Filling d3.js map with colors depending on data from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization

So new to d3, this is my first project using the library. Currently, I'm having issues with filling the map with different colours depending on the data. I found lots of examples on the web but they are not really working for me.

What I have is a JSON file with data in this format

```
"Aska": {
    "opening_bal": 138000,
    "total_funds": 1030574000,
    "expenditure_wages": 796017000,
    "expenditure_materials": 234236000,
    "total_expenditure": 1030491000,
    "unspent_bal": 78000,
    "payment_due": 12780000
  },
  "Balasore": {
    "opening_bal": 4660000,
    "total_funds": 233869000,
    "expenditure_wages": 203883000,
    "expenditure_materials": 57571000,
    "total_expenditure": 262518000,
    "unspent_bal": 28658000,
    "payment_due": 2118000
  },
```

I'm able to create the map using GeoJson file. Here is the link to the map: https://mgnregs-d3.vercel.app/filter

I'm thinking of creating an object using the initial category, "opening_bal" eg:

```
{
  "Aska": 138000,
  "Balasore": 4660000
},
```

and on click, I'll update the category to "total_funds" and so on, eg:

```
{
  "Aska": 1030574000,
  "Balasore": 233869000
},
```

but first I need to visualise the initialise the first data. I am not able to do that.

Something like this worked on some projects, but not on my case...

```
d3.json('data.json', function (d) {
    budget.d.properties.pc_name = d.properties.pc_name['opening_bal']
})

var color = d3
    .scaleThreshold()
    .domain(d3.range(2, 18))
    .range(d3.schemeBlues[6])
```

Here is the repo on GitHub: https://github.com/PixeledCode/MGNREGS_D3

Map Component: https://github.com/PixeledCode/MGNREGS_D3/blob/main/src/components/Filter/Filter.js

data.json: https://github.com/PixeledCode/MGNREGS_D3/blob/main/src/assets/data.json

Map GeoJson: https://github.com/PixeledCode/MGNREGS_D3/blob/main/src/assets/odihsa.js

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your problem is with reading a json file or with a translation of values to color codes?

Comment: It's translation of values to colors. Like if I have an object with different ids and respective values, how to fill map with colors depending on values. Thanks

Comment: OK, you have a range of values (let's say __0__ to __100__) and you want to translate each value in the range to a color (let's say from __green__ to __blue__). Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, something like this, {
  "Aska": 138000,
  "Balasore": 4660000
}, These are the ids I have given to different paths of svg element. Want colors based on these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a data object in the following form:

```
const data = {
  "Aska": 138000,
  "Balasore": 4660000,
  ...
},
```

Find minimum and maximum values of the object:

```
const range = Object.values(data).reduce((r, v) => r ? 
  ({min: Math.min(r.min, v), max: Math.max(r.max, v}) :
  ({min: v, max: v})), null);
```

Now, you can write a function translating any value between minimum and maximum to a color. If your color for minimum value is **green** (0, 255, 0), and the color for maximum value is **blue** (0, 0, 255), the function will look like this:

```
const colorUnit = 255 / (range.max - range.min);
const getColorByValue = val => {
  const delta = val - range.min;
  return `rgb(0, ${255 - delta * colorUnit}, ${delta * colorUnit})`;
};
```

Comment: This answer helped. It didn't exactly work, that reduce method to find min, max is not working for me but the idea to pass value and get colour helped a lot. I ended up writing a function to get hsl colour by changing hue and lightness. Thanks a ton

Comment: If you have an array instead of object, the reduce should be different. Let me know the error you get, I'll try to fix it

Comment: The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of null`. There's also a `)` missing in the reduce but the error is coming from something else. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmdy91ub/2/) with the error. Check the console logs.

Comment: You're right, there were 2 errors in reduce, both are fixed :). If everything else is right, please mark the answer as correct, I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: brackets position still have issues. Other than that, it's working. 

`const range = Object.values(data).reduce((r, v) => r ? 
  ({min: Math.min(r.min, v), max: Math.max(r.max, v)}) :
  ({min: v, max: v}), null);`

Also, the returning colour is in this format `rgb(0, 119.10141156371489, 135.8985884362851)` do we need to round off the values or these will work?

Comment: Just checked `reduce` in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/nemkovca/, do not see any problem...

Comment: I meant in the answer, the one I put in comments is brackets fixed.

Comment: Regarding the color values, you can put `Math.floor()`. If you use `Math.round()` you can get a possible value of 256 which is out of range... In any case rounding does not change much